# Correct way to store values to check against inputs

Tags: java

I'm just learning Java and am a little confused on a sample problem I hit in the book I'm going through. The program asks for me to accept a 2 char string, one letter for colors and the 2nd for numbers.

My values are r=red, b=blue, y=yellow, o=orange, g=green for the first char, and 2nd is 1=first, 2=second, 3=third, 4=fifth, 5=fifth.

For example, if the user entered "r3", I would output "Red came in third!". I want to #1 check to make sure each char is a valid char, and then #2 match up each char to a key to get the full value for that key.

How can I do this in Java? I want to just use a mutli dim array, but then I can't set my keys to the one char values, and the elements to the full values. I can't seem to find a data type that lets me do this. For example

```
array("r" => "red", "b" => "blue", "g" => "green)
```

EDIT: Note, the book wants me to use if/else statements, but that's trivial/boring so I'm trying to do this how I normally would in other languages.

Comment: I believe you're looking for a `Hash Table`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

Comment: Hash Table is it. Thanks Rohan!

Comment: Parallel arrays, or an array of objects that have two fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HashMap (java.util.HashMap). HashMap is somehow similar to dictionary in C#.

You should create to different hashmap for color and position.
You can get value from the hashmap by key.

For example:

```
 public static void main(String a[])

    HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map1.put("r", "red");
    map1.put("b", "blue");
    System.out.println(map1.get("r"));


}
```

output will be : red

Hope this will work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a `Hashmap`. Here is how I have it in my head, assuming I got the problem right.

First, take the input, say `r1`. Extract the first character from it and that will be your color code. Keep a `HashMap` that maps all color codes to their full names. So, in this case, `r` should give you `red`.

Then, create another `HashMap` to keep track of positions of the colors. You just retrieved `red` from first `HashMap`. You can use this as the key for second `HashMap`.
Enter the second character as the value of `red`.

Now, you can properly retrieve the values.
Here are couple of stupid tables I made:

```
|r | red   | // Table one, to map characters to full 
|g | green | // color names.
|b | blue  |


|red   | 1   | // Now that you have color names,
|green | 2   | // retrieve their positions (or insert, whatever).
|blue  | 3   |
```

There is another option and that is to create a custom class to store color and positions. You could thus use only one `HashMap` and accomplish the task. Your `HashMap` would look like:

```
|r | {red,1}  |
|g | {green,2}|
|b | {blue,3} |
```

So, if you get an `r`, use that as the key to the `HashMap`. The value for that key would be a customized object that would contain the full name of the color and the position you entered.

Here is pseudocode:

```
HashMap<Character,MyObject> map = new HashMap<>();
String input = "r1";
char colorCode = input.charAt(0);
char colorPos = input.charAt(1);

if(colorCode == 'r'){
    MyObject my = new MyObject("Red",colorPos);
    map.put(colorCode,my);
}// mode conditionals

//add code tp retrieve using map.get();
```